# Select with Dependency On Each Other and values preselected in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have one page with a first request where I recover all the  necessary data for my page.

This information is like this one:

"A1": 8, 
"A2": 61, 
"A3": 585, 
"A4": null.........etc

Where every value is the id of a specific select which one is loaded in knockout:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <label class="obligatory">*</label>
    <label for="id_A1">A1</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.A1List, optionsText: 'A1name' , optionsValue: 'idA1', value: $data.A1, optionsCaption: '---------------'"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <label class="obligatory">*</label>
    <label for="id_A2">A2</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.A2List, optionsText: 'A2name' , optionsValue: 'idA2', value: $data.A2, optionsCaption: '---------------'"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <label class="obligatory">*</label>
    <label for="id_A3">A3</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.A3List, optionsText: 'A1name' , optionsValue: 'idA3', value: $data.A3, optionsCaption: '---------------'"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <label class="obligatory">*</label>
    <label for="id_A4">A4</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.A4List, optionsText: 'A4name' , optionsValue: 'idA4', value: $data.A4, optionsCaption: '---------------'"></select>
</div>
```

These select have Dependency On Each Other in function of the choice you choose:

```
root.A2List = ko.observableArray([]);
root.A2ListFuncion = ko.computed(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: RUTA_GLOBAL + "/api/A2/",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        type:'GET',
        data: {
            A1: root.Data().A1()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            root.A2List(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
        }
    });

}, root);
root.A3List = ko.observableArray([]);
root.A3ListFuncion = ko.computed(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: RUTA_GLOBAL + "/api/A3/",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        type:'GET',
        data: {
            A1: root.Data().A1()
            A2: root.Data().A2()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            root.A3List(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
        }
    });

}, root);
root.A4List = ko.observableArray([]);
root.A4ListFuncion = ko.computed(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: RUTA_GLOBAL + "/api/A4/",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        type:'GET',
        data: {
            A1: root.Data().A1()
            A2: root.Data().A2()
            A3: root.Data().A3()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            root.A4List(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
        }
    });

}, root);
```

I got all the values ​​of every select Correctly , but I lose the correct value or id Which one Should be selected the first time the user make the request . I understand due to computed list of my select , feature I want but I need the first time When the pre -selected value  in every select the first time the page is loaded.

Any idea?

Comment: Your code example is not complete. Where do you assign values to A1, A2, A3, A4? This should be done after creating your computed observables A*ListFunction. Also, you usage of knockout computed observables is very odd. Better replace it with knockout subscribe function to improve readability.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand you, the code is complete

Comment: You problem is because bindings "value: $data.A1" are executed before lists A1List, A2List, A3List, A4List are populated with values. In this case knockout will not find corresponding option and will reset value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Artem by your clue:

```
root.A3ListFuncion = ko.computed(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: RUTA_GLOBAL + "/api/A3/",
        dataType: 'json',
        ***async: false,***
        type:'GET',
        data: {
            A1: root.Data().A1()
            A2: root.Data().A2()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            root.A3List(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
        }
    });
```

Changing the ajax request to async false the problme was resolved.